# How to delete a single row from the table fast?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table and I want to delete the first row containing a particular value. If I would have to select the first row containing a particular value I would use `select x from table where x = 5 limit 1` and the query would be fast - no need to scan the whole table, it would stop after finding the first matching value. However, if I use `delete` clause with a subquery, it still scans the whole table.

Example of slow query: `delete from table where x in (select x from table where x = 5 limit 1);`

The question is how to make the delete query stopping after finding the first matching value. In this table I also have primary key if this may help here.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I use Postgresql as said in the description

Comment: so you should delete mysql tag ...

Comment: you're right, deleted it

Comment: Why do you not then find the row by select and then delete it without conditional clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if x is unique, you don't need the `limit 1` in your SELECT query.

And did you try this?

```
delete from table where x = 5;
```

There is no need for a subquery, the WHERE clause you use in the SELECT query can be directly used in the DELETE query.

Just be aware that if x is not unique, it will delete all rows where x = 5.

Comment: It still needs to scan the whole table. I want to find a way to tell the query to stop after it finds the first matching row and to delete only it -- that's why I tried ```limit```.

Comment: The query does not really scan the whole table, it'll only look at the given columns (x) and if x is a primary key or has an index, the search will be even faster. There should be no performance loss anyway

Comment: Well, that helped

Comment: See [postgres' indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/indexes-types.html) for more infos on indexes type, default one being [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)

Answer (score 1):

Do you try this :

```
delete from table where id in (select id from table where x = 5 limit 1);
```

maybe your x column is not indexed

Comment: yes I've tried, but it still scans the whole table and doesn't stop after the first entry